# Issues while adding shadow to the custom CLLayer Mask

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I need to create this type of view

[image]

Here is what I was able to create [image: create]

Here is the overriden `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let aPath = UIBezierPath()
    
    let curve: CGFloat = 8
    let inset: CGFloat = 15
    let maxHeight = rect.height - 20
    let minWidth: CGFloat = 2
    
    if isLeftCurved {
        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: minWidth + curve, y: 0))
    } else {
        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    }
    
    if isLeftCurved {
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width-minWidth, y: 0))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width-minWidth, y: maxHeight))
    } else {
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width-curve, y: 0))
        aPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: curve), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: maxHeight-curve))
        aPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width-curve, y: maxHeight), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: maxHeight))
    }
    
    aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2+inset, y: maxHeight))
    
    aPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2-inset, y: maxHeight), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2+inset, y: rect.height), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2-inset, y: rect.height))
    
    if isLeftCurved {
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: minWidth + curve, y: maxHeight))
        aPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: minWidth, y: maxHeight - curve), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: maxHeight))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: minWidth, y: curve))
        aPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: minWidth + curve, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: minWidth, y: 0))
    } else {
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: minWidth, y: maxHeight))
        aPath.close()
    }
    
    R.color.segmentBackgroundColor()?.setFill()
    aPath.fill()
    R.color.segmentBackgroundColor()?.setStroke()
    aPath.stroke()
    
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = aPath.cgPath

    let stroke = CAShapeLayer()
    let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: maxHeight), radius:
        CGFloat(11), startAngle: CGFloat(-90.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(270.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)
    selectionColor.setStroke()
    circlePath.lineWidth = 1
    circlePath.stroke()
    stroke.path = circlePath.cgPath
    layer.insertSublayer(stroke, at: 0)
    
    if isSelected {
        let circlePath : UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: maxHeight), radius:
            CGFloat(6), startAngle: CGFloat(-90.degreesToRadians), endAngle: CGFloat(270.degreesToRadians), clockwise: true)
        selectionColor.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()
        let stroke = CAShapeLayer()
        stroke.path = circlePath.cgPath
        layer.insertSublayer(stroke, at: 1)
    }
    
    self.layer.mask = layer
}
```

The only problem is the shadow, I have tried to add shadow to the `self.layer`, `self.layer.mask`, but same output. So what it the correct way to add shadow to the custom `Layers` or `UIBezierPath`. Thanks.

Comment: What about adding a UIView container above it, and apply the shadow do it? As an easy fix?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I will need to make curved container to have curved shadow, isnt it the same problem, can I have a rectangular container view with this kind of curved shadow?

Comment: On iOS shadow shows on the semi/fully visible pixels, and ignoring none-visible ones. Meaning that if you'll have a container above it, and apply shadow to the container, and the container has a clear background, the shadow will show up exactly like you want in the right image.

Answer (score 0):

One easy(not optimised or widely appreciated) solution is to have shadow as part of the whole container image, this covers the bottom radio buttons as well.